# Why does Spring Security return 403 in Postman or on the browser?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, http-status-code-403

I don't understand. What is it about this code that prevents me from POSTing from the login page `/user/login` by returning the 403 error status code?

I have disabled the CSRF and I always get 403 response both from the browser and Postman.

I am given the impression JWTVerifier is always called when I POST to `/login`

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(request -> {
            var cors = new CorsConfiguration();
            cors.setAllowCredentials(true);
            cors.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
            cors.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept",
                    "Jwt-Token", "Authorization", "Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                    "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
            // exposed to the front-end
            cors.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Jwt-Token", "Authorization",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
            cors.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
            // /** -> all routes in the back-end app, the configuration will be applied
            return cors;
        })
                // we're not using sessions, not keeping track of currently logging in users
                // users prove by using a token -> stateless
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS) //
                // open for everyone <- no authentication
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll() //
                // anything else - reqs. authentication
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and() //
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

PUBLIC_URLS is a String[] constant with the value { `"/user/login", "/user/register", "user/resetpassword/**", "/user/image/**" };`

Comment: is it might be about bad credentials when you trying to login, i was have a similar problem it was returning 403, i also recommend you to check if you have commence method.Thats probably where it return 403.

Comment: and your debug logs are telling you?